# ¿Porque no se reproduce un Video en iphone | HTML CSS?

Tags: css, html5

¿Como puedo hacer para que me reproduzca automáticamente un video "background" en iphone? He visto que algunas paginas sin problema lo hacen, pero no se como logarlo.

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="elvideo">
<source src="imagenes/videoback.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not ssubeport HTML5 video.
</video>

//estilos
#backvideo {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;

position: fixed;    
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checa esta página y tendrás una solución posible con la compatibilidad

https://css-tricks.com/full-page-background-video-styles/